# Increase row height of only one element in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have text where I display in every element of a set of 3 columns by 17 rows.  I have it so that each set of text is limited to 100 characters, but there is a `more` button I have implemented where if you click it, it will show the rest of the characters. Each element varies in text length. The problem is, when I click more, the entire row height expands, versus just expanding that element's row height. That would mean if I clicked the `more` button for the first element in the row, but haven't clicked the `more` button for any of the other elements in that row, the row height would expand because you have more text to display, but all the other elements that haven't been expanded have a lot of white space underneath themselves because of the first element's expansion in text. Is there a way to simply expand only that element's row height, but keep the row height the same for all the other elements in that row? Below is my attempt:

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="datasourceRow in datasourceRows track by $index">
    <div ng-repeat="datasource in datasourceRow track by $index" class="col-sm-4">
        <p style="color: gray; overflow: hidden;" dd-text-collapse dd-text-collapse-max-length="100" dd-text-collapse-text="{{datasource.description}}"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.directive('ddTextCollapse', ['$compile', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // start collapsed
            scope.collapsed = false;

            // create the function to toggle the collapse
            scope.toggle = function() {
                scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;
            };

            // wait for changes on the text
            attrs.$observe('ddTextCollapseText', function(text) {
                // get the length from the attributes
                var maxLength = scope.$eval(attrs.ddTextCollapseMaxLength);

                if (text.length > maxLength) {
                    // split the text in two parts, the first always showing
                    var firstPart = String(text).substring(0, maxLength);
                    var secondPart = String(text).substring(maxLength, text.length);

                    // create some new html elements to hold the separate info
                    var firstSpan = $compile('<span>' + firstPart + '</span>')(scope);
                    var secondSpan = $compile('<span ng-if="collapsed">' + secondPart + '</span>')(scope);
                    var moreIndicatorSpan = $compile('<span ng-if="!collapsed">... </span>')(scope);
                    var lineBreak = $compile('<br ng-if="collapsed">')(scope);
                    var toggleButton = $compile('<span class="collapse-text-toggle" ng-click="toggle()">{{collapsed ? "less" : "more"}}</span>')(scope);
                    // remove the current contents of the element
                    // and add the new ones we created
                    element.empty();
                    element.append(firstSpan);
                    element.append(secondSpan);
                    element.append(moreIndicatorSpan);
                    element.append(lineBreak);
                    element.append(toggleButton);
                    element.append(detailsLink);
                }
                else {
                    element.empty();
                    element.append(text);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

CSS:

```
.collapse-text-toggle {
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color: #666666;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.collapse-text-toggle:hover {
    color: #222222;
}
.collapse-text-toggle:before {
    content: '(';
}
.collapse-text-toggle:after {
    content: ')';
}
```

EDIT: Added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g7z6jgnb/2/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using bootstrap based on your class names. If that's the case then no I don't think you could isolate the single element in that row and expand it without creating white space underneath the other elements.
You could just not create a new row for each set of three elements. Encase all elements inside of one row and if they all have the class designation col-md-4 then you will still only have at most 3 per row and you can let them re-size independently of each other. 
Otherwise I would consider utilizing a popover or modal to display more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are setting collapsed value true and false which is applicable to your all buttons, need to make that a unique identifier. if you can try sharing a fiddle link.

```
       // start collapsed
        scope.collapsed = false;

        // create the function to toggle the collapse
        scope.toggle = function() {
            scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;
        };
```

at this part either create an array for collapsed having $index as identifier :

```
       scope.collapsed[$index] = true;
      // something like this will work
```

Comment: Where would I add that last part? How does this allow me to only expand one element's row height?

Comment: When you change scope.collapsed value it does everywhere. You can share fiddle link,   I can edit for you. Hope that helps

Comment: $index can act like identifier which will only allow button to expand for that particular row.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you're saying replace `scope.collapsed = !scope.collapsed;` with `scope.collapsed[$index] = true;`? Let me try to set up a fiddle link... might take some time though.

Comment: Hi, I have created a Fiddle but I can't seem to run it.. Not sure why. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/g7z6jgnb/ I have also provided it on my question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/anshuli/g7z6jgnb/1/ it runs now.. you can follow this tutorial for running angular applications on fiddle https://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/

Comment: And also your code doesn't work, so first make it work then the issue can be resolved.

Comment: This was my best try... Thanks for trying to help me though. I can't seem to get it to run. https://jsfiddle.net/g7z6jgnb/2/ No worries, Ill just try to find another work around. thanks.